# flash of unstyled jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery UI tabs and I'm bothered by the flash of unstyled content until the widget loads. I'm trying to display loading image before tabs load but I can't get it to work. Please advise. Thanks.

```
$(function() {
var loading = "img src='spinner.gif'";
$("#productTabs").html(loading).tabs();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...prevent_a_FOUC_.28Flash_of_Unstyled_Content.29_before_tabs_are_initialized)?

Comment: This means put display:none on the tab containing div and change that to display:block after the tab initialization occurs?

Comment: I tried the link you refer to. Its not what I'm looking for. It hides the tab contents without giving a user any kind of feedback. I want to display the loading spinner image to give user feedback that the widget is about to be displayed.